# Error parsing validation.xml: null

Tags: hibernate, xml-parsing, bean-validation

While trying to use a Bean Validation (JSR-303) custom constraint, using annotations and XML configuration as [described here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-customconstraints), I am getting the following error in logs and the constraint is ignored:

```
<Error> <org.hibernate.validator.xml.ValidationXmlParser> <BEA-000000> <Error parsing validation.xml: null>
```

I am using Weblogic 12.1.1 as application server and my application is deployed as a war file.

Both the **validation.xml** and the **constraint-mapping.xml** files are put under WEB-INF/classes/META-INF.

Does somebody have a clue what might cause this? Is this a dependency or conflicting library issue?

Here is my **validation.xml**:

```
<validation-config xmlns="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration">
     <default-provider>org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator</default-provider>
     <constraint-mapping>META-INF/constraint-mapping.xml</constraint-mapping>
</validation-config>
```

And my **constraint-mapping.xml**:

```
<constraint-mappings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                     xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/mapping validation-mapping-1.0.xsd"
                     xmlns="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/mapping">
<constraint-definition annotation="foo.CustomConstraint">
    <validated-by include-existing-validators="true">
        <value>foo.CustomConstraintValidator</value>
    </validated-by>
</constraint-definition>
</constraint-mappings>
```

Thanks in advance,

Dimitris

**UPDATE**

---

After following Gunnar's suggestion I did the following:

- Overriden the Weblogic's default hibernate validator (4.1.0) with version 4.3.1
- Debugged the ValidationXmlParser class.

This gave me the following exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-25004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461):
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: An error occurred unmarshalling the document
Internal Exception: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 96;
SchemaLocation: schemaLocation value =
'http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration' must have even number of URI's.]
```

In order to overcome this, I've updated the *xsi:schemaLocation* in **validation.xml** as follows:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration
                    http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration/validation-configuration-1.0.xsd"
```

This change fixes the previous error but my annotation continues to be ignored. What do I miss here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML files seem incomplete (see [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#chapter-xml-configuration) for a complete example):

- `validation.xml` is missing its closing `</validation-config>` tag
- `constraint-maping.xml` must have `<constraint-mappings>` as root element

AFAIK WLS 12.1.1 still uses Hibernate Validator 4.1.0 which unfortunately swallows any `JAXBException`s raised during unmarshalling `validation.xml`. If the problem remains, I recommend to debug the issue using the Hibernate Validator 4.1.0 sources and inspecting the `JAXBException` caught in [ValidationXmlParser:L216](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/4.1/hibernate-validator/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/xml/ValidationXmlParser.java#L216). In later HV versions the root exception is propagated as well.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The missing tags you mention are included in the files, it's just my bad on pasting the code here (I'm totally new to SO :D). I've also updated the the main question.

Comment: With the `constraint-definition` element you only configure the validators for a given constraint type, but you don't yet apply the constraint to any type or property. To do so, either put the `@CustomConstraint` annotation to the elements to be validatd or add the constraint via XML using the `constraint` element etc. See the Hibernate Validator [reference guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-mapping-xml-constraints) for an example.